# Mock multiple calls to the same method in spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I am currently writing unit testcase for a groovy application

```
class Page{
   ..
   ..
   str1 = obj.getDateBasedOnValue("A");
   str2 = obj.getDateBasedOnValue("B");
}
```

Test class

```
class PageSpec extends Specification{
   Obj obj = Mock(Obj)
   ...
   def "testCase 1"(){
      obj.getDateBasedOnValue(_) >> "some date string 1"
      obj.getDateBasedOnValue(_) >> "some date string 2"
   }
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is the right way to mock both the calls in spock? If no then please guide me towards the right solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To return different values on successive invocations, use the triple-right-shift (>>>) operator:

```
def "testCase 1"(){
    obj.getDateBasedOnValue(_) >>> ["some date string 1", "some date string 2"]
}
```

Then `getDateBasedOnValue()` will return `"some date string 1"` for the first time and `"some date string 2"` for the second time.